# Inserting scale bar in ArcScene?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, arcscene, scale-bar

In layout view of ArcMap it is easy to add a scale bar.

In ArcScene there is no layout view and no insert a scale bar tab.

How do I add a scale bar in ArcScene?

Comment: Have you seen [How to display the scale bar in ArcScene](https://community.esri.com/thread/17347)?

Comment: I draw a line and did it manually as suggested in the link

Comment: Nice! You could answer your own question if you want to

Answer (score 1):

This is a manual method not a built in feature of ArcScene. 
First open the "3d editor", "enable current z", than draw a line from "3d graphics", which the length you defined before.